# Adding a digital signature to a pdf on a hexadecimal level in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, hex, digital-signature

I wanted to know if there was any native way to add Digital Signatures to PDF files in c#. I wanted to avoid using iText or http://developer.arx.com/ until I have given up.

I wanted to know where a digital signature is added to a pdf file in relation to the byte offsets. That way I could just manually add it in when I read a file in as a byte array, then use

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\location\signed.pdf", newlyMadeByteArrayToFile);

.

I have a feeling this is oversimplifying this. I tried to find documentation on pdf files offset tables, but couldn't find much/not looking in the right places.

Is this worth attempting further, or should I just use iText or http://developer.arx.com/.

Comment: With "native" way you will end up rewriting the PDF signing library. With enough time and inspiration you can accomplish this, but it's just waste of time.

Comment: I concur. If you do want to start rolling your own digital signature solution, start by reading http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures If you think reading a 150-page book is too much work, know that writing digital signature functionality for PDF is even much more work that requires much more reading. We are currently hiring Black Duck to find out why people write things such as "I want to avoid using iText". It would help if you filled out this survey. https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/iText-community Based on the answers, we may be able to make it acceptable for you to use iText.

Comment: In addition to writing a PDF signing library, you also need to worry about how/where you will be creating/managing/storing the private signing key(s) for your signer(s). It is a poor practice to leave the signing keys in a file system, that's where secure signing appliances become useful.

Comment: Ah, ok. The mean reason I was avoiding it was due to "forseeable compatibility issues. I also just wanted to know if there was already something inside of c# that handled this.

Answer (score 0):

The overall answer was yes, but not worth it. Thank you everyone.